# fread and fwrite not returning false on bad attempts

Tags: php

Consider this code:

```
$a = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
$b = fread($a, filesize('test.txt'));
```

I'd expect `$b` to be false, since it's obviously trying to read from a file which is only open for writing. However, `$b` is in that case an empty string. How do I distinguish between a bad attempt and a legit empty file? Same applies to `fwrite()` btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definition of `fread()` it will almost always return a string result value except in these two cases:

1. The first argument is not a valid resource,
2. A length of zero or less is specified as the number of bytes to read.

In your case, you could detect a bad attempt with code like this:

```
if (($data = fread($f, 512) === '' && !feof($f)) {
    // nothing read but not at EOF either
    // that's fishy
}
```

In case of `fwrite()` you can test how many bytes were written (it's the return value); if less bytes were written, something is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
$content  = false;
$filename = 'test.txt';

if( $handle = fopen($filename, 'a') )
{
   $meta = stream_get_meta_data($handle);

   // Check if mode readable
   if( $meta['mode'] == 'r')
       $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

   fclose($handle);
}

if( $content == false )
    echo 'bad attempt!';
```

I tested and output is:

```
bad attempt!
```

Comment: Did you test this? `$content` will be an empty string.

Comment: It wasn't me, but this doesn't really answer the question that was asked, which is how you can distinguish a bad read attempt and an empty file.